# Parsing data in deep link

Tags: android, deep-linking

In my application, I am using deep linking. Here is the flow of my application, on registration user gets email from web

```
 http://test.abc.com/testing?email=YWtzLmtuaXQxMTA4QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
```

but on web side there is deep uri along with details

```
 abc://testing/email/YWtzLmtuaXQxMTA4QGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==/id/20
```

If I get Scheme from data then it is returning test.abc.com

is it possible to get details of deep uri, as in IOS there is default method which is returning full url.

Is there any way in android as well?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can get the full deep link url.

You can get it in your target activity from the `Intent` data like this :

```
Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
    String uri = this.getIntent().getDataString();
    Log.i("YourApp", "Deep link clicked : " + uri);
}
```

Comment: the code `String uri = this.getIntent().getDataString();` returning full url like `iptv2://xtream-editor.com/en/get/m3u/DFSDFDS` while I only need `/xtream-editor.com/en/get/m3u/D2EEEA95CCD180C7D6A9CC1CA9C95873`

Comment: you might've configure it like that to include `iptv2://`, you can get rid of it by simply using the substring : `uri = uri.substring(7)` @MuhammadMuazzam